# Rectangle packing algorithm with desired position?

Tags: c#, algorithm, rectangles

I'd like to implement a variation of a rectangle packing algorithm in C#. In my case the rectangles have a width and height and a "desired" position in a 2D plane (on the screen). They must however not overlap. I want the algorithm to find the positions of the rectangles that minimizes the distances of their desired positions. I am aware that the order in which the rectangles are placed plays a role but I can't even find a performant algorithm for a fixed or random order. Anyone got an idea or references?

More formal definiton of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEJAv.png)

Comment: Just to maybe make the problem more clear, here is a terrible approach: put in the rectangles one after the other at their desired position. Then, if a new rectangle overlaps with at least one existing one, adjust the position (pixel wise) by moving it in an outwards spiral around the desired position until no rectangles overlap.

Comment: So the "two-dimensional knapsack problem" or "geometric knapsack problem"? A quick google search will give you plenty of papers on the topic.

Comment: As far as I understand, they might both be related but not the same problem. In the two-dimensional knapsack problem the boundary (capacity) is limited while in my problem it is not, a subset of items fit is a valid solution while I want to fit all rectangles and the positions of the rectangles is irrelevant while in my problem they are vital. And the geometric knapsack problem is about enclosing points in space with a boundary, which is something completely different: no positioning, overlapping, ...

Comment: This is way too broad and unfocused for this site!

Comment: I added a formal definition of the problem, hope that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented @tiliavirga's suggestion and it works quite well.

**Some notes:**

- I made the repulsive force proportional to only the square root of the overlapping area because otherwise, the first few iterations had huge repulsive forces blowing the constellation apart. (On the other hand, it leads to quick termination which could be important, see below)
- I reduced the attractive force over time towards 0, because otherwise, the alg oscillates in some cases, where overlapping rectangles are pushed away, then in the next iteration pulled together, then pushed away, and so on
- The algorithm can take very long, depending on the parameters (1) how quickly the attractive force weakens, (2) how large the motion of the rectangles is in each iteration, and (3) the limit of the total overlapping area which can be tolerated, terminating the algorithm. In time-critical applications, e.g. in games where this computation is done every frame, these parameters should be adjusted to result in a quick termination with a not-so-optimal solution.

All in all, a good enough solution for me. Python code below:
DATA STRUCTURE:

```
class Rect(object):

    def __init__(self, centerX, centerY, width, height):
        self.centerX = centerX
        self.centerY = centerY
        self.desired_centerX = centerX
        self.desired_centerY = centerY
        self.left = centerX - width / 2
        self.right = centerX + width / 2
        self.bottom = centerY - height / 2
        self.top = centerY + height / 2
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.centerX += x
        self.centerY += y
        self.left += x
        self.right += x
        self.bottom += y
        self.top += y
```

UTILITY:

```
def normalize(vector):
    length = np.linalg.norm(vector)

    # define the normalization of the zero vector like this, because we need to move rectangles
    # somewhere when they are perfectly centered on each other
    if length == 0:
        return np.random.rand(vector.shape[0])
    else:
        return vector / length

def isOverlapping(r1, r2):
    #we define that a rects doesn't overlap with itself
    if r1 is r2:
        return False
    if r1.left > r2.right or r1.right < r2.left or r1.bottom > r2.top or r1.top < r2.bottom:
        return False
    return True

def getOverlappingArea(r1, r2):
    if not isOverlapping(r1, r2):
        return 0
    else:
        return (min(r1.right, r2.right) - max(r1.left, r2.left)) * \
                (min(r1.right, r2.right) - max(r1.left, r2.left))

#pointing from "r1" to "r2"
def getScaledPushingForce(r1, r2):
    overlappingArea = getOverlappingArea(r1, r2)
    if overlappingArea < 0:
        raise ValueError("Something went wrong, negative overlapping area calculated!")
    if overlappingArea == 0:
        return np.array([0,0])
    return np.sqrt(overlappingArea) * normalize( \
                np.array([r2.centerX - r1.centerX, r2.centerY - r1.centerY]))
```

PARAMETERS:

```
# the strength of the pulling force towards the desired position decays to easy termination
# higher value = slower decay
# faster decay means faster termination but worse results
pullingForceHalfTime = 10

# the overlapping area which is considered to be small enough to stop the algorithm
# (recommended to assign according to the number and size of the rectangles)
acceptableOverlap = 2*len(rects)

# the scaling of the total forces, that moves the rectangles
# larger portions mean faster termination but possibly worse results 
# (recommended 1/2<= forceScaling <= 1/20, the smaller pullingStrength is, the lower should forceScaling also be
# e.g. forceScaling = 1/20 * pullingStrength)
forceScaling = 1/10
```

ALGORITHM:

```
# calculates pulling and pushing forces and moves the rectangles a bit in the direction of the combination of these forces
# in every iteration. Stops when the overlapping area is sufficiently small
def unstack():
    i = 1

    #iterate until break
    while True:
        #pulling forces towards the desired position
        #weakened over the course of the iteration (depending on d), since no overlapping is the stronger constraint
        pulling_forces = [np.array([r.desired_centerX - r.centerX, r.desired_centerY - r.centerY]) * \
                          np.power(0.5, i/pullingForceHalfTime) for r in rects]
        #pushing forces resulting from overlapping rectangles
        #the directions of the forces for a pair of overlapping rectangles has the direction of the connecting vector
        #between their centers and the magnitude is proportional to the are of the overlap
        pushing_forces = [np.sum([getScaledPushingForce(r_, r) for r_ in rects], axis=0) for r in rects]

        total_forces = np.sum([pulling_forces, pushing_forces], axis=0) * forceScaling

        #move the rectangles by a portion of the total forces (smaller steps => more iterations but better results)
        for j in range(len(rects)):
            rects[j].move(total_forces[j][0], total_forces[j][1])

        #stop iterating when the total overlapping area is sufficiently small
        if np.sum(np.square([getOverlappingArea(r[0], r[1]) for r in itertools.combinations(rects, 2)])) <= acceptableOverlap:
            break

        i += 1

    #print results
    finalDistancesFromDesired = [np.array([r.desired_centerX - r.centerX, r.desired_centerY - r.centerY]) for r in rects]
    print("Total distances to desired positions: " + str(np.sum(np.linalg.norm(finalDistancesFromDesired, axis = 1))))
```

and an example run through:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4KU.gif)

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). some notes: 1) link-only answers are considered as low-quality ones and will be removed. you should bring all the code needed directly in your answer, then you can add links to other external resources if you want. 2) all contributions are welcome in Stackoverflow, “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful.” I'll edit and fix this one for you. you can fix the number `1`